# How to speed up readings from serial port data

Tags: c#, serial-port

I am writing a small app that a customer will use to read data off a scale.

The issue i am having is that there is a HUGE delay from when the scale actually has weight on it and it displaying in the software. With hyper terminal it is accurate and immediate, with the code below after its been running for about a minute i have to wait around 40 seconds for the count to update.

The scale is set to 19200 BAUD rate and cannot be dropped lower or it will miss readings.

I'm using SerialDataReceivedEventHandler but I'm not sure if this is the fastest way possible.

below is my code is there anyway i can speed this up?

and I cant afford to miss any readings

How do i set a Buffer or speed this up, or should i read in the bytes instead of using readline?

I have tried removing all formatting from the string and just have it write raw to a text file as well, this unfortunately only made it slower.

```
 private void StartReadBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        port = new SerialPort(ComLbl.Text, Convert.ToInt32(BaudLbl.Text), Parity.None, 8, StopBits.One);
        try
        {
            port.Open();
        }
        catch
        {
            port.Close();
            port.Open();
        }
        port.DataReceived += new SerialDataReceivedEventHandler(DataReceivedHandler);
    }

    //Event Handler to read com port data
    private void DataReceivedHandler(object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
    {
        SerialPort sp = (SerialPort)sender;
        try
        {
            sp.Open();
        }
        catch
        {

        }
        CommData = sp.ReadLine();
        if (readingcount < 7)
        {
            readingcount++;

        }
        else
        {
            OldCom = Convert.ToInt32(oldData);
            try
            {
                NewCom = Convert.ToDecimal(CommData.Substring(5, 5));
            }
            catch
            {
              //incase a string is caught with incorrect characters 
            }
            label1.Invoke(new Action(() => label1.Text =CommData));

        }

    }
```

I need this to be responsive enough that i can actually read data into the software live and not seconds behind the scale. If i look at Hyperterminal, the scale transmits around 60 lines of data every second, and i need to be able to catch them all, live

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps because you are using ReadLine() as you think for yourself.

[ReadLine()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.ports.serialport.readline?view=netframework-4.8) assumes text data ending with the NewLine property value. It does not end until it receives a NewLine value code or a timeout occurs.

Instead of ReadLine(), read [BytesToRead property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.ports.serialport.bytestoread?view=netframework-4.8), specify the data size, and execute [Read()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.ports.serialport.read?view=netframework-4.8).

Then, carefully check whether the received data conforms to the data format described in the programming guide for the scale device.

Otherwise, it is wrong to do Open() at the beginning of DataReceivedHandler. If that is really necessary, there may be something wrong elsewhere, and that would have required Open().

Also, creating a SerialPort object each time you click the StartReadButton is a bad use.

The programming guide for the scale device seems to describe commands such as reading start/stop and zero scale, and how to use them. Create a program according to that.